# mysql select random users but more chances for those with lower votes

Tags: php, mysql

Hello can someone help me with a query like i said in title? Atm i dont have any ideea how to make that. What i want is when i press on a  button to display users random but those with lower votes to have more weight in the random sql.

here is my actual sql

```
$query = "select * from `users` where username!='$user' ".$conditie_categ." order by  RAND()  limit 1 ";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
        or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Thnx in advance.

Comment: How many users did you need ?

Comment: well when u press next button u'll get a new user random but i want those with lower votes to have prio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crudely...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+


SELECT i
     , RAND()/(i+1) wght 
  FROM ints 
 ORDER 
    BY wght DESC;
+---+-----------------------+
| i | wght                  |
+---+-----------------------+
| 1 |    0.4722126251759125 |
| 0 |    0.3937836097495478 |
| 3 |     0.217650386474701 |
| 2 |   0.18025848441470893 |
| 4 |   0.14613628009905694 |
| 7 |   0.11937898478412906 |
| 8 |   0.08080622240562157 |
| 9 |   0.07711844041675184 |
| 5 |  0.006933732585609331 |
| 6 | 0.0022811152594387277 |
+---+-----------------------+
```

Lower values *tend* to appear towards the top of the list.

Comment: seems your sql is working as i want, just i changed DESC to ASC cause i want lower valus to be first ones, Thnx :)

Comment: can u tell me how is this working? it takes random vote and it divide it to the i+1 then it orders by the result?

Comment: Yes. There are probably better algorithms for weighting - but I'm no statistician!